# jQuery - How to work out height based on 100% width?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a banner that I'd like to be full width across all devices.

This works out the width perfectly fine:

```
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth,
    bannerHeight = "100px";

    $('.banner').css({"background-size" : windowWidth + "px " + bannerHeight, "height" : bannerHeight});
```

However, I'm struggling to figure out how to work out the ACTUAL height of the background image so it shows perfectly in the correct resolution.

Any help would be great!

Here's a fiddle of what I have:
**http://jsfiddle.net/52wow970/**

Comment: Is there only a single banner you're doing this for?  If there are multiple banners, are they all the same size? You will have to figure out the aspect ratio for the banner to do this, or if you really want to use javascript, you have to get the original size by preloading the image

Comment: are you talking about the background-size height or the bounding box height?

Comment: Also is there a reason you want to make it a background image?  If you dont' just make it an image http://jsfiddle.net/52wow970/2/

Comment: @ntgCleaner Thanks for your reply.  There will be multiple banners, but they'll all be the same size.  Ideally I'd like it to be a background image as I'd like to sprite all of my banners together.

Comment: You may need to look into aspect ratio, or taking the image dimensions ans setting the background based on that. To be honest, I would not use background images for this case and do <img style="max-width: 100%"/> but that's just me.

Comment: Try this...

http://jsfiddle.net/52wow970/3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull the image info then resize the banner...

```
var tmpImg = new Image();
tmpImg.src="http://redspadetheater.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/slider_stage-300x130@2x.jpg"; //or  document.images[i].src;
$(tmpImg).on('load',function(){
  orgWidth = tmpImg.width;
  orgHeight = tmpImg.height;
  alert(orgWidth+"x"+orgHeight);
    $('#container .banner').height(orgHeight)
});
```

Also change background-size: to "cover"

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52wow970/4/

Comment: Thanks for your help!  How would I also resize the height based on the width?

Comment: Nick do you mean preserve aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, judson implementation is good. My version gets the image url from the background image property:

```
var backgroundImg = $('.banner').css("background-image");
var imgUrl = backgroundImg.substring(4,backgroundImg.length-1);
var img = new Image();
img.src = imgUrl;
var widthRatio = windowWidth/img.width;
bannerHeight = widthRatio* img.height;
$('.banner').css({"background-size" : windowWidth + "px " + bannerHeight, "height" : bannerHeight});
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of your banners are going to be the same size, don't use javascript at all.  You can do it in CSS pretty easily, even with a background image.  You just need to find out the aspect ratio of your banner.

Your banner in the fiddle example is 600x260px.  This means you have an aspect ratio of 43.333%  (260/600).  Keep that 43.333% in mind.

You need to set up your HTML like so (Like you have it):

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="banner"></div>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS just use the `:before` pseudo class.

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    position:relative; /* You need this in here for the positioning of your banner*/
}
#container:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    padding-top:43.333%; /* Here's that magic number */
}
#container .banner {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image: url('http://redspadetheater.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/slider_stage-300x130@2x.jpg');
    background-size:cover; /* Using cover will make the image full width/height */
}
#container .banner img {
    width:100%;
}
```

The before element uses the `padding-top` as your height.  For some reason that I'm still not completely sure of, any percentages given in the `:before` element, use the width of its container as 100%.  So 43.333% of the width of the container is the desired height.

Here's a fiddle demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/52wow970/5/

Answer (score 0):

Do it without JS

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52wow970/6/)

```
#container .banner {
   background: url('http://redspadetheater.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/slider_stage-300x130@2x.jpg') no-repeat;
   background-size: 100%;
   padding-bottom: 43.4%;
}
```